# How to pass the timestamp in the query param of NodeJS (Express + Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have MongoDB command like this:

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
   {
      "$match": 
         {
          $and:[{
                  'is_deleted': false,
                   'createdAt':{'$gte': ISODate('2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z'),'$lte':ISODate('2020-12-15T00:00:00.000Z')}, 
                   'type': 'deposit'
                }
               ]
         }
         
   },
   {
       $group: {
          _id: null ,
          depositRevenue: {$sum: "$amount"}
        }
   }
]).pretty();
```

And the output like this:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "depositRevenue" : 324
}
```

The query is fine, but when I pass in NodeJS it's not work.
Bellow is my code in ExpressJS and Mongoose.

```
      let revenueData = await Transaction.aggregate([
       
        {
          $match: {
           $and: [{objFind}]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            totalRevenue: {$sum: "$amount"}
          }
        }
      ]);
```

with `objFind` like this:

```
    var startDate = new Date(req.query.startDate).toISOString();
      var endDate = new Date(req.query.endDate).toISOString();
      var objFind = {};
      objFind["is_deleted"] = false;
      
      if(startDate != undefined || endDate != undefined){
        objFind["createdAt"] = {};
        if(startDate != undefined){
              objFind["createdAt"]["$gte"] = startDate;
        }
        if(endDate != undefined){
              objFind["createdAt"]["$lte"] = endDate;
        }
      }
       objFind['type'] = 'deposit';
```

Please take a look. Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simplify your code,

- create an object with required conditions

```
var objFind = { 
    is_deleted: false,
    type: 'deposit'
};
```

- check start date and end date available

```
if (req.query.startDate || req.query.endDate) {
    objFind.createdAt = {};
    if (req.query.startDate) objFind.createdAt.$gte = new Date(req.query.startDate);
    if (req.query.endDate) objFind.createdAt.$lte = new Date(req.query.endDate);
}
```

- by default root fields condition would be and condition, so no need to use `$and`

```
let revenueData = await Transaction.aggregate([
    { $match: objFind },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            totalRevenue: { $sum: "$amount" }
        }
    }
]);
```